# Is there a way to upload logs from website (javascript logs) to a server?

Tags: javascript

I would like to upload javascript logs to an online server(specifically any exceptions). Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps use AJAX - but why do you wish to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "javascript logs" ? I assume you know that uploading data to a server is possible in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send log to server via ajax, example with jquery:

```
$.post("/log/save.php", 
    log: "Hello world", 
    function(){ 
        console.log("log saved") 
    }
);
```

then in `/log/save.php` connect to database and save to logs table **or** save log to file:

```
<?php
$file = 'logs.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new log to the file
$current .= $_POST["log"]."\n"; //hello world.
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```